# How to make z3 recognize equivalence of certain arithmetic expressions?

Tags: z3

I have a pretty simple problem, I'm mentioning the relevant part here:

```
;; All variables are declared to be of type Real

(assert (and (<= 1.0  var1-r) (< var1-r 4.0)))
;;following defines var1-r
(assert (= var1-r (+ a b)))
;;following defines var1-e
(assert (=> (and (<= 1.0 var1-r) (< var1-r 2.0)) (= var1-e 8388608.0)))
(assert (=> (and (<= 2.0 var1-r) (< var1-r 4.0)) (= var1-e 4194304.0)))
;;following defines var1
(assert (= var1 (/ (foo (* var1-r var1-e)) var1-e)))

;;Similarly for var2-r, var2-e, var2
(assert (and (<= 1.0  var2-r) (< var2-r 4.0)))
(assert (= var2-r (+ b a)))
(assert (=> (and (<= 1.0 var2-r) (< var2-r 2.0)) (= var2-e 8388608.0)))
(assert (=> (and (<= 2.0 var2-r) (< var2-r 4.0)) (= var2-e 4194304.0)))
(assert (= var2 (/ (foo (* var2-r var2-e)) var2-e)))
```

Here, `foo()` is a simple interpreted function, eg., `foo (x) = (to_real (to_int x))`
Note that `var1` and `var2` are equal. Reason: `var1-r` and `var2-r` are equal (commutativity of Reals) and consequently `var2-e` and `var1-e` are equal, leading to `var1` and `var2` being equal. However, I am not able to prove unsatisfiability of `(not (= var1 var2))` using z3. In fact, the same is true if `var2-r` is defined as `(+ a b)`. [Note that `var1` and `var2` being equal is actually also independent of the definition of `foo()`].

Answer (score 1):

Please look at  [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Ibjf).  I am obtaining

> `unsat`

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, it does produce unsat if `foo` is just declared as you did. But as I mentioned in my post my `foo`, I need `foo` to be this: `(define-fun foo ((x Real)) Real (to_real (to_int x)))` as I don't know beforehand when an uninterpreted `foo` is also good enough.

Comment: You are right.  As far as I understand the problem are the values 8388608 and 4194304.0 which are very large. I am testing your definition of function "foo" with very low values and your code works and produces "unsat".  Do you agree?

Comment: The greater values with "unsat" :  498.0 , 497.0

Comment: Agreed. These constraints come from encoding a problem in a specific domain, and these large constants are always cosecutive powers of 2. I got back unsat for 512.0, 256.0 in a few seconds. Thanks, I'll also see if your suggestion of using uninterpreted function (though not the ideal solution) can be put to use in some way